# Help understanding this implementation of cons and car in scheme using lambdas

Tags: lambda, scheme, sicp

My question relates to the following code:

```
 (define (cons. x y)
   (lambda (m) (m x y)))

 (define (car. z)
   (z (lambda (p q) p)))
```

My problem is with how this code actually works. As far as I can understand cons. is returning a procedure containing the variables x and y within its scope. car. then takes the returned procedure from cons. and applies it to another lambda that takes two arguments p and q and returns p. My confusion lies within that second lambda, where exactly do the values of P and Q come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variables `p` and `q` are the two elements of the "cons cell"; i.e., they are the `x` and `y` in `cons.`.  If you run `(car. (cons. 1 2))`, you get (expanding `cons.`):

`(car. (lambda (m) (m 1 2))`

which turns into (using the definition of `car.`):

`((lambda (m) (m 1 2)) (lambda (p q) p))`

Plugging the argument into the body of the first `lambda`, you get:

`((lambda (p q) p) 1 2)`

Another substitution like that gives you `1`, the first element of the "cons cell."